# Best Practice Signed Arithmetic On Unsigned Values for 8 Bit Processor

Tags: c, math, optimization, signed, keil

Whats the best practice to find the signed difference between 2 unsigned values in C to take the least instructions?
This is the best I can see without asm.

```
int16_t difference(uint8_t x,uint8_t y)
{
    return (int16_t)x-(int16_t)y;
}
```

Comment: C automatically promotes `uint8_t` values in arithmetic expressions to `int`, so `x-y` computes the signed difference. No casts are needed or useful. It is up to the compiler to use the most efficient instructions, and you generally have little control over that other than enabling optimization. If you need more control, then write in assembly language.

Comment: Thanks. Im using the old C51 compiler for a 8051 micro. Without the cast my results were coming out wrong thats why the cast is added in my example.

Comment: Then this is not a C question; it is a my-quirk-old-non-standard-C-Keil-C51-compiler question. Answers for standard C cannot help you, and useful answers have to be based on specific knowledge of the compiler.

Comment: Especially if you are using a specific compiler, you cannot apply general best practice. You need to look at all solutions you can think of. Use the compiler's options to generate assembly or listing. C51 is known to be non-compliant. Guard your solution with a compiler check or at least write an explanatory comment.

Comment: Out of interest, besides being redundant, do the casts in my example change the way a standard C compiler would interpret that code compared to `return x-y;`?